# Scala warning: abstract type pattern Z is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure

Tags: scala, type-erasure

I've taken a look to the answers about this topic, but I just haven't got how to fix the problem in this snippet:

```
object MyObj {

  def validate[Z](json: JsValue)(implicit rds: Reads[Z]): Either[Error,Z] = {
    json.validate[Z].map{ 
      case r: Z => Right(r)  // Type Erasure here....
    }.recoverTotal{
      e => Left(JsonParsingError(JsError.toFlatJson(e).toString))
    }
  }

}
```

Any help?

Comment: Just read the notification for the edit you proposed -- I suggest keeping it as a `Reads`. You can apply it to a `JsValue` by either doing `readsEither.reads(json)` or `Json.fromJson`, and then you can safely use `.get` on the resulting value to unpack the resulting `JsSuccess`, because you know `readsEither` already recovers all possible failures. It's a bit more verbose, but it's more idiomatic and composable that way. I also just added another possibly more succinct way to go directly to the `Either` if you don't want to go the `Reads` route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you really have to do to kill that error is drop the type ascription `: Z`. You already know it will be a `Z` if `validate` gives you a `JsSuccess` in the first place. Otherwise you'll end up in `recoverTotal`.

I think you want:

```
object MyObj {
  def validate[Z](json: JsValue)(implicit rds: Reads[Z]): Either[Error,Z] = {
    json.validate[Z].map(Right _).recoverTotal{ e => 
      Left(JsonParsingError(JsError.toFlatJson(e).toString))
    }
  }
}
```

Although what you may really want is:

```
implicit def readsEither[Z](implicit rds: Reads[Z]): Reads[Either[Error, Z]] = Reads { json =>
  rds.reads(json).map(Right(_)).recoverTotal { e => 
    JsSuccess(Left(JsonParsingError(JsError.toFlatJson(e).toString)))
  }
}
```

This latter example is nice because it defines a `Reads`, which composes nicely.

I haven't tested any of this, and can't really, since I don't have a `JsonParsingError`, but this should more or less solve your problem.

**Edit**: given the fact that your code requires an implicit `Reads[Z]` already, you might also try:

```
def jsonAsEither(json: JsValue)(implicit rds: Reads[Z]) =
  Json.fromJson(json).asEither.left.map( /* ... */ ).e
```